# how to check for multiple types of validations in one table

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset, database-table

So I have a scenario.

Must have these 4 application fees set up with no end date or end date in future.

```
(FeeTypeID = 16 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18)
(FeeTypeID = 17 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18)
(FeeTypeID = 18 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18)
(FeeTypeID = 19 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18)
```

Now how would I put this into a if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND and OR:

```
select ...
from ...
where  
(
  (FeeTypeID = 16 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18) or
  (FeeTypeID = 17 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18) or
  (FeeTypeID = 18 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18) or
  (FeeTypeID = 19 AND FeeRequirementTypeID = 18) or
)
and
(
  end_date is null or
  end_date > now() -- or whatever expression your dbms uses for today
);
```

EDIT: I just notice that ist always FeeRequirementTypeID = 18. So simply:

```
select ...
from ...
where FeeRequirementTypeID = 18 
and FeeTypeID in (16,17,18,19)
and ( end_date is null or end_date > now() );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is great for the SQL Side. If I wanted to put this in a If statement? How would I go about doing this? Or would it be better to put it in the select statement when populating the datatable? Because the data is coming via a stored procedure I do not think I could put this in the SP as the SP is bringing in other data which I am using elsewhere.